# Formatting Integer in Python

Tags: python, string, ascii, newline, blackmagic-design

This is the Request I get from an BMD Hyperdeck, it contains the Video-files on the SD-Cards an the lengths of the Videos. I need the lengths of every file, separate in a List for my Code. What would be the right way to something like this?

```
b'206 disk list:\r\nslot id: 1\r\n1: Timecode.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:01:00:00\r\n2: Video_1.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:00:09:07\r\n3: Video_2.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:00:07:04\r\n4: Video_3.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:00:10:19\r\n5: Video_4.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:00:04:16\r\n6: Video_5.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:00:05:21\r\n\r\n'
```

Comment: Where are the file lengths? Do you mean the video lengths like `00:00:09:07`?

Comment: Split the string into lines. Remove the first two header lines. Then you can split each line into words and get the word you want with the length.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the regular expressions and `findall`:

```py
import re

a = b"206 disk list:\r\nslot id: 1\r\n1: Timecode.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:01:00:00\r\n2: Video_1.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:00:09:07\r\n3: Video_2.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:00:07:04\r\n4: Video_3.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:00:10:19\r\n5: Video_4.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:00:04:16\r\n6: Video_5.mp4 H.264 1080p25 00:00:05:21\r\n\r\n"
str_a = str(a)
length = re.findall(r"[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0:9]{2}", str_a)
print(length)
```